Questions about definition and examples from two youtube videos on Colon ideals/Ideal Quotients
Questions  I would like to know for the two reference youtube lecture videos below.  I am not certain what is meant by the usage of the words/phrase: divide, dividing, dividing by, divided by in Video 1 and the phrase quotient out in Video 2.   The instances where all those said words/phrase appears, have been italized and bolded.  The lecturer, when he uses those four words/phrases, I am not sure if he means in an analogous wy or literally in the mathematical sense. Because also in Video 2, the way the phrase quotient out is use, does it mean the definition of colon ideal/ideal quotient only apply to ideals where its ambient ring is a ring with unity and the ideal itself must have units.
To be more explicit, for Video 1, the definition of $I:S$ contains the relation $xS\subseteq I, \forall s\in S$. Since both $I,S$ are ideals, then  for some $i\in I, xs\in I$ implies $xs\mid i$.  Is this the correct interpretation of the words/phrase: divide, dividing, dividing by, divided by in Video 1?
For Video 2 for the phrase quotient out, at $((xz,yz):(z))=\{p:\forall a, \exists b, c\;\; paz=bxz+cyz\}=\{p:pa=bx+cy\}$, where $paz=bxz+cyz$, we move everything to the left, set it equal to zero, factor out the $z$, $paz-bxz-cyz=z\cdot(pa-bx-cy)=0,$ since $\Bbb{C}$ is an integral domain, then $z=1\neq 0$.  At this point, $z=1\neq 0$ requires that $F$ of $F[x,y.z]$ be an integral domain, and the fact that $F=\Bbb{C}$ allows for terms in $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ to be invertible.  But that doesn't answer the question of what happen if $F$ is an integral domain only.  Nothing in the definition of ideal quotient require that the ambient ring is a field.
This last point relates back to what I asked in Video 1, that is what happen if the commutative ring $R$ is the ring of matrices, then it seems that any ideals of such ring, and including the concept of ideal quotient would require elements in the ideal quotient to be invertible??
Thank you in advavnce.
Background
Below are typed out defineition and examples along with relevant transcript portions concerning explanations for Colon ideals/Ideal quotients.  For the video, the transcript can be found here.  I typed out the relevant transcript portions along with the noted time stamp for those who doesn't want to watch the videos.
Video 1 Lecture 6 - Colon and Radical of Ideals
Definition of Colon idea

Colon Ideal
Let $I$ be an ideal & $S\subseteq A$. Then
$I:S=\{x\in A:xs\in I, \forall s\in S\}$
$=\{x\in A:xS\subseteq I\}$

At 2:15
Professor: "Subset any set so I am loooking at all elements which will multiply $S$ inside $I$ or in other words or in a you know in a general sense, where we are we are taking ideal $I$ and dividing by all elements of $S$ in some sense right.  We are looking at all $x$ such that $xs$ is in $I$ for every $s$ so we are taking all elements of the form $xs$ and divided by $s$ in $S$.   That is, you know vague meaning of taking colon.  We will look at this we will see so this is also you can also write this as $x$ in $A$ such that $xs$ is in $I$.
Example 3 At time stamp: 6:10, and at time stamp 6:57
At 6:10

$(3)$ $A=F[x]$ $I=(x^2)$ $S=\{x\}$
$I:S=(x^2):x=(x)$ $\quad (Ex:)$

Professor: "Ok, now let us look at some simple examples let me take $I$ so ah my ring is let's say any field any PID any field $F$ and any polynomial ring $F[x]$ over $F$.  Take $I$ to be equal to $x^2$ and $S$ is $x$"
At 6:57
Professor:  "So what wold be $I$ colon $S$ I am look at all elements in. All polynomials in...  Will $1+x$ be there?"
Student:  "Constant term will be zero"
Professor: "Right so this is so this is $x^2$.... so in some sense now  you are saying all polynomials with constant term zero and that is generated by....that's ideal generated by $x$.  So what have we done we have just divided that is exactly what I said here we are simply dividing this $(x^2)$... in the normal cases in the first examples what we see is that we are basically dividing them....you know dividing by elements of $S$... so this is the ideal generated by $x=(x)$.
Example 4  At time stamp 8:19 and at 9:30 to 13:34

$(4)$ $A=F[x,y]$ $I=(x^2y,xy^2)$
$S=\{y^2\}$
$I:S=\langle x,? \rangle$
$x^3y, x^4y,\dots$
$x^2y^2, x^2y^3, x^2y^4,\dots$
$x^3y^2, x^4y^3,\dots$

At 8:19
Professor:  "So let us look at one more example.  I am sorry... ah $A$ is $F[x,y]$"
at 9:30 to 13:34
Professor:  "so let us look at another example let me write this as $I=(x^2y,xy^2)$ and take my $S$ to be $y^2$.  So what would be $I$ colon $S$?  Can you tell me what would be $I$ colon $S$?  There is there is an obvious element there
Student:  "x"
Professor:  "ah...$x$ is there, right. So lets let's let's see if we can find the generate ah generators of this. $x$ is there, do we have something else?  can we think of some other element?  See here, you have to look at...ah.. maybe I will...ah... see we have to look see we have to divide all the elements of $I$ by $y^2$ and see what are the elements.  Now from here can you think can you think of elements that you can obtain from here? $x^3y, x^4y,\dots$ and so on.  Right, you multiply this element by $x^2, x^3$ and so on and you get this.  Another possibility is $x^2y^2, x^2y^3, x^2y^4$ and so on, right.  These are another set of elements in this ideal another set is in a combination of these two, $x^3y^2$ and then again $x^4y^3$ and so on. imilarly, for this one; so when you divide by $y^2$ this none of them is divisible by $y^2$ right, this has only $y$ term there. So you cannot really divide this by $y^2$, now dividing this by $y^2$ square what do you get? $x^2, x^2y, x^2y^2$, but when we are considering the ideal and we are trying to you know specify the generators of the ideal do we need to mention $x^2, x^2y, x^2y^2$ and so on. Because if $x^2$ is there, $x^2y$ is there, and if that is there $x^2y^2$ is there and so on. So we only need to make sure that this element is there, but now from the other one we already know $x$ is there. So $x^2$ is also superfluous. Because that you can obtain from $x$. So the question is, is there anything more here, OK? So exercise. Find $I : S$ in this example, OK? And find means you have to prove whatever the ideal, if you are trying to prove that it is generated by $(x)\ldots$.
Video 2 Operations on Ideals
At time stamp: 21:53

Example:  $((xz,yz):(z))\subseteq \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$
$((xz,yz):(z))=\{p:p(z)\subseteq(xz,yz)\}$
$\{p:\forall a, \exists b, c\;\; paz=bxz+cyz\}$
$\{p:pa=bx+cy\}$
$(x,y)$.

"..so kind of nicely we have this factor shared between the two generators of the original ideal when we quotient out by the ideal that generates it falls away and we are left with the ideal (x,y)..."

It is not that relevant as you think. Just read reference text for precise definition.

@user264745 the reason I made the post because when I look at from the interpretation of containment = divisibility, then does that imply the ideal has to contain invertible elements.  I think the definition involves one to be proficient in doing calculations.  The second video where the phrase "quotient out" is used, does that mean canceling out elements from both sides of a equation and hence the definition doesn't imply an ideal quotient doesn't necessarily mean that the ideal itself don't contain invertible elements?  Another thing is, I would rather I ask on here whether I understand..

@user264745 .... I understand the nuance of a definition.  I think this is one of those cases where it doesn't hurt to ask

Asking is not bad, I agree.

@user264745 can you shed light on my confusions please.  I just feel that that the definition requires further elucidation than standard definitions from textbook references.

@user264745 sorry I should have been a bit more explicit in my replies.  I was responding on my phone while ridingg the bus.  So, for the second video, at the point where it says:  $((xz,yz):(z))={p:\forall a, \exists b, c;; paz=bxz+cyz}={p:pa=bx+cy}$, where $paz=bxz+cyz$, we move everything to the left, set it equal to zero, factor out the $z$, $paz-bxz-cyz=z\cdot(pa-bx-cy)=0,$ since $\Bbb{C}$ is an integral domain, then $z=1\neq 0$.  At this point, $z=1\neq 0$ requires that $F$ of $F[x,y.z]$ be an integral domain,...

@user264745 ....and the fact that $F=\Bbb{C}$ allows for terms in $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ to be invertible.  But that doesn't answer the question of what happen if $F$ is an integral domain.  Nothing in the definition of ideal quotient require that the ambient ring is a field.  I am going to edit my post to be a bit more explicit about what I am confused about, maybe that will clarify things up.  I will let you know here after I have done so.

@user264745 I edit my post and added more info about what my confusions are and what motivated my feeling of lack of clarify in the definition,, etc.

Why $z=1$? Here $z$ is an indeterminate.

@user264745 if $z=1$ is false. then how does $z$ get cancelled?

Coefficient of $z$ on both side must be equal, I guess.

@user264745 wait, if coefficients on both sides are equal, but the ambient ring is only an integral domain, can cancellation operation still be possible?

If you're working in an integral domain, then cancellation law  holds.

@user264745 if it is okay, can we continue this in chat.  I don't know how to initiate it actually.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
